# Electric charge difference weapon?

Tags: charge, lightning

*We all know how lightning works: The clouds have a strong static charge and release that charge towards the ground. But could it be used as a weapon?*

**Would a weapon of the following description work? Would it be practical for mass destruction?**

A strongly negatively charged piece of metal is fired at a target. Then, a machine builds up a very strong positive charge. Because of the charge difference, a strong electrical current flows through the air and strikes the target.

Comment: Lightning contains relatively little energy, so the answer is no.

Comment: What I was more thinking was that the heat created by this lightning would certainly be damaging. Also, the average lightning strike is ~70,000 volts.

Comment: Voltage doesn't do the damage, energy does. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvesting_lightning_energy a lightning strike doesn't contain more energy than fits into the fuel tanks of a few vehicles. This is comparable with the chemical energy stored in a mid size conventional explosive ordinance bomb. An American made MOAB probably contains about almost two orders of magnitude more energy than that. I don't think even the latter weapons are being counted among WMDs.

Comment: What is wrong with a taser?

Comment: +CuriousOne Well, V=IR. If resistance is low and voltage is high, current must be strong. And strong current damages nerves, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weapon you are suggesting is similar to one where a laser pulse ionizes the air to the target and channels a high voltage high current charge to the target. It requires extremely high power laser pulses in the femtosecond region.
The name of the tech is [Electrolaser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolaser)

Answer (score -1):

This weapon [exists and is commercially available](https://www.taser.com/products/x2).  The amount of heat discharged is minimal, but it's excellent at disrupting electrical oscillators like hearts and low-current electrical pathways like nerves.

Comment: This clearly isn't what OP was thinking; the last paragraph states, *A strongly negatively charged piece of metal is fired at a target....a strong electrical current flows through the air and strikes the target.* That is, a *singular* piece of metal hits the target and the current flows *through the air* to hit the target. A taser requires both electrodes to be on the target.